# Visual Studio 2019 erro vetor

Tags: c

Boa noite , alguém sabe me dizer por que aparece essa mensagem no programa em linguagem c, e se tem como resolver? 
 **Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'nota' was corrupted**.
O float ta nota[3] por que vetor começa contando no 0 entao teria que estar certo com 4 numeros.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main() {

    float nota[3];

    nota[0] = 8.5;
    nota[1] = 7.5;
    nota[2] = 10;
    nota[3] = 10;

    printf("A primeira nota = %.2f\n", nota[0]);
    printf("A segunda nota = %.2f\n", nota[1]);
    printf("A terceira nota = %.2f\n", nota[2]);
    printf("A quarta nota = %.2f\n", nota[3]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "por que vetor começa contando no 0 entao teria que estar certo com 4 numeros." Na verdade você indica que ele terá 3 índices, como o primeiro índice é 0, ele finaliza no nota[2]

Comment: Se é para ter 4 notas tem que declarar como `float nota[4];`.  O numero na declaração é o tamanho e não a ultima posição.

Answer (score 0):

Barbetta, eu sei que isso é meio confuso do C, mas vamos analisar. Na declaração do vetor float de nota você coloca quantas deseja, se você deseja 4 notas, então você faz nota[4], tudo bem até ai? Agora para acessar o índice do vetor ou para percorrer utilizando um for, por exemplo, você sempre faz (tamanho do vetor - 1). Logo seu código ficaria:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main() {

   float nota[4];

   nota[0] = 8.5;
   nota[1] = 7.5;
   nota[2] = 10;
   nota[3] = 10;

   printf("A primeira nota = %.2f\n", nota[0]);
   printf("A segunda nota = %.2f\n", nota[1]);
   printf("A terceira nota = %.2f\n", nota[2]);
   printf("A quarta nota = %.2f\n", nota[3]);

   scanf("%[^\n]");

   return 0;
```

}

Ah! Outra coisa, não utilize **system("pause")** para segurar a tela do prompt, isso é desnecessário, o prompt no fim do programa sempre fica esperando, agora caso você deseje deixar isso explícito, use a função que está no código a cima.